# How can I test a flow with ActiveMq in local

Tags: testing, mule, activemq-classic, integration-testing, mule-studio

I'm started to work with Mule and Mule Studio (version 3.5): my goal is rewriting some flows that now is workign, but with a bad syntax.

In this moment I have a flow with some JMS connector and JMS endpoint for acquiring data (my flows are using ActiveMQ 5.10): the configuration XML file is ok and I want to test this flow, but I have'nt a big experience in JMS and system integration.

I think to create a JMS producer and, into run,

1. start up Mule (with all his flows, endpoints, etc, JMS queues);
2. start the JMS producer: in run the producer
3. links to name queue defined in configuration Mule
4. create a message
5. send this message to Mule

And the test asserts the

1. Mule receive the message by the producer
2. Mule don't loss the message
3. Mule turn this message to correct flow and relative elaboration

My problem is the lack of manuality and pratical work-ability to link Mule and producer: I tried to use http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html but the code is useless for me because it work correctly without Mule, but in my case the tests has to fail if Mule is stopped.

Has everybody any suggest, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up an activemq connector without addresss, that will use the default address of vm://localhost that instructs the connector and activemq to act as a local embedded server.

```
  <jms:activemq-connector name="JmsConnector" specification="1.1" />
```